# How to find user in google admin sdk

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-api, google-admin-sdk

I'd like to find if user with certain username exists on my Gmail. So far I tried:

```
String query = "email='"+username+"@my.domain.com'";
users = directoryService.users().list().setQuery(query).execute();
```

But I only get:

```
13:47:12.654 [1651372403@qtp-1044945601-1] ERROR p.e.u.d.g.a.m.SDKGAManagementServiceImpl(153) - com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
    {
      "code" : 400,
      "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "Bad Request",
        "reason" : "badRequest"
      } ],
      "message" : "Bad Request"
    }
```

I tried to query for a user with known username and I got desired response so I'm certain that the issue lies here. Could someone provide any help?

Comment: Your description is not clear. Do you want to check if user exists using admin sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the user using admin sdk, then you should give query like query=email=xxxx@domain.com. Also, even though its not mentioned in documentation, for users.list,you should give domain name too.

After giving the above parameters, I was able to successfully find the user. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: So the query should look like this: `String query="email="+username+"@domain.com"`? Without apostrophes?

Comment: Documentation for admin sdk is abysmal. Setting up domain solved my problem.